# Absolute continuity of distribution function

Tags: probability, density-function, measure-theory

I have a question about the distribution function $F(x)$.

There is statement in (K.V.Mardia, Statistics of directional data) about the circular distribution function (which has all the properties of normal distr.f., and some others which correspond to periodicity of this function).

Firstly, he defines a distribution function, let´s say in normal way as for the line equivalent and then he is saying:

$Theorem:$ If the distribution function is absolutely continuous, then it has density function and it holds
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=F(a)-F(b).$$

What I do not understand is how abs.c. of $f$ implies the existence of a density function. Because, normal way of deriving density is that, you need integrable, non-negative function s.t. 
$$P(X \in B)=L-\int_{B}fdx.$$
(where L denotes lesbegue integral).
And with some effort, you can show that 
$$F(x)=\int_{B}f(x)dx$$ 
and that $F^{'}(x)=f(x).$

But as I am looking at it,the theorem  is mentioned in opposite direction. But I need function $f(x)$ with mentioned properties and then i can show that $F(x)$ is abs.c., and relationship that $f(x)=F^{'}(x),$ but not vice versa. Or am I missing some theorem about Lesbegue integration or something?

Comment: There are relevant theorems here, but whether you need one depends on your definition of "absolutely continuous": which one are you using?

Comment: The whole book is intended for statistician, so there are a lots of definitions missing. But i suppose that it´s normal definition of abs.c. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity . If i would ask you, could you please post the answer for case of more definitions of abs.c. funcitons and with theorems? it would be so thankful to you.

Comment: That Wikipedia article gives multiple different definitions.  See its section "Equivalent definitions" as well as the final section "Relation between the two notions of absolute continuity."

Comment: I am really sorry. I would say the first $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition. But it´s hard to say, since this property is used just for this defintion.